# eclipse debug stop on error line

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

In Visual studio when an error happens during debug, the line causing the error is jumped to in the source code and the error displayed.

Is there a way with Elcipse to do the same? The Debug perspective appears, but the line causing the error and the error message are not immediately apparent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working with Java, so the answer is yes. You can tell Eclipse to break on exception. From the **Run** menu, select **Add Java Exception Breakpoint...**. Now, you need to select the Exception class. If you wish to stop on all Exceptions, you can use `java.lang.Throwable`. You can also specify whether to stop on caught or uncaught exceptions.

You can (and should) also use it for assertions, as I outlined in [this post](http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/05/using-java-assertions-use-an-assertionfailed-breakpoint.html).

Comment: To catch all Throwables, will also need to tick the "Subclasses of this exception" checkbox when the Throwable is highlighted in the Breakpoints view.